# Detect Missing object in a single image

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

In the image there are 2 insulators, the one on the left has a gap i.e a disk missing in between. I have to detect the missing disk with a rectangular box. I know alogorithms SIFT and SURF or by using absdiff() in opencv for calculating difference between two images.
How can i can detect the missing disk if I only have this image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3aY9.jpg)

Comment: What is "missing object" in your question? and what do you mean by "point the missing disk"?

Comment: In the image there are 2 insulators, the one on the left has a disk missing in between. i have to detect the missing disk with a rectangular box.

Answer (score 1):

You should find contours,bounding boxes and circles.After that you can find missing object or noise objectt. Other way to use AI to fit objects and search for that. But this one is very hard job

Answer (score 0):

General algorithm (it's obviously):

- find insulators
- find gaps
- find insulators with gaps.

I think, insulators are kinda standardized by size and look. So, probably, you can detect them by color/texture and/or some specific details. They can't be very "curve", so you can estimate them with lines and separate overlapped elements. If all insulators have same size, than you can normalize them, stretch by one axe, and then detect gaps.

Their is no way to do 100% correct recognizing in all cases, but you can use some knowledge about insulators and get good results.